# See the post data of forms

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, http-post

I'm making a chrome extension to fill forms.

When the user clicks on the forms send button, I need to read the POST request. 
Is it possible? 
I can't find any method, only a onBeforeRequest,  but in this link it says that this is a chromium issue.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191

Comment: Don't understand this question.

Comment: Sorry for my english ;) I only need read the post request. When user send form I want read the form inputs, selects.. Etc..

Comment: You can use JavaScript to get the values of all the form elements.  You can do this without submitting the form.  Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know, but I need get the values when the form its submitted. On in the submit moment..

Comment: The idea is, to intercept the submission before it happens.  Then use Javascript to do the actual submission.  (I'll update the answer with that.)

Comment: Ok, not is this.. :) I cant modify the form, not is in my web. I need use a chrome extension for intercept the submission. Without modify a button for add the function. See the firts link on firts post, its writed with perfect english :))

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form, it looks like this.  Should be enough to get you started.

```
 <form name="thisform" id="thisform" action="submissionpage.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" value="some value" id="first" />
  <input type="text" value="some value" id="second" />
  <input type="button" onclick="javascript:readValues()" value="see values" />
</form>


    function readValues() {
  var firstValue = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var secondValue = document.getElementById("second").value;

  alert("First:" + firstValue + "\nSecond:" + secondValue);

    var messageIs="";
    if (messageIs=="") {
            document.getElementById("thisform").submit(); 
        }else{
            alert(messageIs);
        }
}
```